# Is "my bad" a correct English phrase?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality, idioms, colloquialisms

I have seen many people use the phrase "my bad" in Internet forums. What does it exactly imply and is it a proper English phrase?

Comment: FWIW, it is commonly used in American speech, not just on the internet.

Comment: This phase sounds awfully silly. Thankfully it is rarely heard outside America.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, "my bad" is a proper English phrase. It is an apology; when you say "my bad", you're basically saying, "I admit a mistake" or "my fault, sorry for that". Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/my_bad):

> *(colloquial) (idiomatic)* My fault; mea culpa.
>
> - *Yes, I realize the humvee isn't supposed to be parked in the heirloom flowerbed. My bad.*

It also links to [this Language Log entry](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002693.html), which provides further insight:

> The authoritative discussion of the phrase "my bad!" at [this Random House site](http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20000111) says it originates in pick-up basketball as a phrase used by young urban players when admitting to an error. It has spread to other domains and is now used widely to mean something like "I admit that I have made a mistake." It was nominated for "word of the year" (not that it's a word, it's clearly a phrase) in 1999, but in fact it was already [at least twenty years old](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001927.html) by then.

Comment: Note that while *proper* in some sense, this phrase is definitely colloquial (as Wiktionary says). For best results, don't use it in formal contexts.

Comment: Note that "my bad" is an Americanism, but would be understood (through 'cultural' exposure) my most other native English speakers.

Comment: I'm from California.  I had never heard this expression until I moved (in the late 1980s) to the (US) East Coast. Fwiw.  Here it is ubiquitous.

Comment: "Yes, "my bad" is a proper English phrase." – This is what Americans actually believe.

Answer (score 44):

It's proper English *slang*.  I wouldn't go so far as to say it was proper English.

It will certainly be effective in irking English teachers, haters of textspeak, and other grammar purists!

Comment: "Your bad *what*?"

Comment: If you are going to complain about using an adjective as a noun, you better get down the Statue of Liberty with a chisel.  "Your tired *what*?  Your hungry *what*?  'Huddled masses yearning to breath free', that's OK..."

Comment: @Malvolio: I think all those adjectives do actually specifically qualify "huddled masses"... they're not just being used in isolation!

Comment: @ thesunneversets  - mmmm, and "homeless", and "tempest-tost"?  It looks to me like a list of six noun phrases.  And what about "lonely are the brave"?  "The wild and the innocent"?  "The fast and the furious"?  "Blessed are the meek"?  "Afflict the comfortable"?  "The quick and the dead"?  "The naked and the dead"?  "We the living"?  "Fear of the unknown"?  "The bitter with the sweet"?  "The calm before the storm"?  "The still of night"?  "The young and the restless"?  "The old and the sick"? "The lame and the halt"?  "My one and only"?  "The long and the short of it"?  Almost out of characte

Comment: @Malvolio - I would upvote that comment multiple times if I could.  (Obligatory _[Bob Roberts](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103850/)_ quote: "I wish there was a way I could vote for you a hundred times." "There is... Just kidding.")

Comment: @thesunneversets How many of these adjectives would do well with a possessive rather than a definite article. Some, but few. "My bad" sounds more like a frozen expression than like a nominalization as in your examples. I think your comment does not sustain linguistic analysis.

Comment: @babou speaking as someone who grew up with this as the most colloquial way to apologize, to me it is very clearly a noun in this context. You could even say something like "OK it's not your bad, but whose bad is it?" This is a purely dialectical thing, so the fact that it sounds awkward to you is based on that.

Answer (score 11):

To my ear "my bad" is very much an Americanism. Handle with care.

Answer (score 6):

Concrete Gannet is right. "my bad" is very much an Americanism. I had not heard this until recently, and was baffled when I did. I heard it on American television programmes and a computer game. I have not heard any British people use it.

To me, it's like the Americanism "I could care less". It does not actually, make sense. It might be acceptable and even considered as proper English in the USA but, it is not elsewhere. At least not in the UK. It does not make sense because, it is an unfinished sentence.

When I have heard it, my immediate thought was, "your bad what?". Your bad behaviour? Your bad language? Or, just your bad English, which this sentence demonstrates?

Comment: How does it not make sense? You're approaching it from the wrong direction. It's not "my bad X" it's "X is my bad". Bad here being a noun representing "fault".

Comment: @treeface your surprising.

Comment: @treeface  according to your response it is obvious that you do not understand grammar. Bad is an adjective, or as you Americans learn it in schools a property. Bad cannot be a noun.

Comment: @Bogdan considering you're not American, it doesn't surprise me that a) you don't understand my point and b) you think Americans are taught that adjectives are called "properties". What exactly are you on about? This is a dialect thing, so there's no need to act pompous.

Comment: And if you read other responses in this thread, it's completely common in all forms of English for adjectives to take noun forms in certain contexts. Just because your dialect doesn't use "bad" as a noun, doesn't mean it's impossible. Again...try broadening your horizons a bit.

Comment: @treeface I undestand your point, but I don't have to agree with it.  I always try to "broaden" my knowledge and sometimes my views, and I understand that languages are dynamic. However, because some people that have not the best education and don't understand grammar, introduce bad expressions. I don't feel compelled to accept and used them, especially when there are correct and simple alternatives, in this case "my mistake". Mistake is a noun, whereas "bad" is an adjective and is grossly misused in that expression.

Comment: It just another example of the tendency of cutting short the expressions because of laziness. A complete form would be "my bad move" or similar.  If we are to continue on the same line, we would end up saying "my perfect",  "my red", etc. My perfect WHAT?   Anyway,  From the grammar point of view is incorrect and the fact that many people use it doesn't make it correct. In fact, many people voted Trump, and this fact doesn't make him the best person on the planet. Democracy, whether is in politics or language evolution has its failures!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a short way to apologize: many people are ashamed when they realise they have been wrong about something, so this may be a shorter and faster way to admit that they were wrong and/or to apologize.

Comment: I sort of agree (or at least this is the best answer I could find). There were plenty of examples but I've never heard "my bad" be used anywhere but by itself. (eg. - Am  I right?  - No, my bad.)

Answer (score -4):

It's a slang, *faux* apology.  It says, "I was wrong, but I'm too haughty to actually apologize for my error."

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. To my ears there's nothing artificial about it, though it's not the kind of thing you'd expect to hear for serious misdemeanors.

Comment: No, it's a real apology, said in haste so as to clear the air, but not distract the teammate, so both players could focus. Obviously, like any sincere phrase, it can be said sarcastically or insincerely.

Comment: the phrase has pick-up basketball origins - the fact that a player would even apologize quickly by saying "My Bad" is commendable in itself - normally, if you make a mistake you just run back :)