# What does "I stand corrected" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

When someone says

> I stand corrected.

What does that mean?

Comment: Yesterday I was telling my friend that my chiropodist improved my posture. He pointed out that it was in fact my chiropractor. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It means "I admit that I was wrong".

See e.g. [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/i-stand-corrected):

> used to admit that something you have said or done was wrong
>   *I stand corrected - the date of foundation was 1411, and not 1412 as I had written.*

Or [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stand_corrected):

> Said to acknowledge someone who corrects something that one says or writes that was not correct.
>
> *The Battle of Hastings was fought in 1056.
>
>   No it wasn't! Look in the textbook!
>
>   Oh, sorry. I stand corrected - it was fought in 1066.*

Note that the Cambridge Dictionary marks this idiom as "formal", and [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/correct%5B2%5D) as "somewhat formal".

Comment: great minds think alike :-)

Comment: @John & @Reg: Two excellent answers to vote for, as ever. I think this website is plagued by having too many skilled experts.

Answer (score 21):

It means, "I admit that I was wrong".

It is often used by a person who has been holding a strong opinion when faced with conclusive contrary evidence.

> John: "My keys are missing. They were stolen!"
>   Mary: "Look in your pocket."
>   John (after finding his keys in his own pocket): "I stand corrected."

Comment: On a lighter note, I doubt the average John would use "I stand corrected" is this context ;-)

Comment: @Jimi - perhaps not the average John, but this one would, and has. :-)

Comment: Would the average @Jimi go with ["my bad"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/is-my-bad-a-correct-english-phrase)?

Comment: @RegDwight: Yes, he most certainly would, as in "Oops, my bad"!! (Thanks for the link!) @John Satta: Nice rejoinder!

Answer (score -1):

It's the softest way to say you were wrong before.

Comment: There are countless ways that are softer.

Comment: Your answer adds nothing to the existing answers, which already explain that the expression means that the person was wrong.